# Best function to use for SQL injection performance

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I would like to know which functions is best to use to prevent MySQL injections

There are plenny of functions I can use to prevent sql injections, such as:

- `mysql_real_escape_string`
- `mysqli_real_escape_string`
- `addslashes`
- casting values (intval etc...) for numbers
- `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES`
- or simply remove the `'` or `"`

I want to standardize my code using the best and faster anti-SQL-injections method and I would like to know which one should I use for high traffic sites.

Comment: Just because this topic comes up *weekly* doesn't make it a good question. Please use the search function.

Comment: Are you using mysql_query(), mysqli_query(), PDO or something else?

Comment: Questions that have 'best' or similar words in the title are rarely the right question to ask on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't use htmlentities for saving data to a database, addslashes isn't 100% secured (some character sets can still make it vulnerable), using mysql_ or mysqli_ is dependent on the driver you're using and not interchangable. Basically, its not a matter of speed or performance - the only right thing to do is using the escape function that comes with your driver (pdo::escape or mysql[I]_real_escape_string) for strings and casting integers/floats to their correct type.

Comment: how addslashes ins't 100% secure?

Comment: @XinQianCh'ang: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes (found via [the search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20why%20isn't%20addslashes%20secure%20against%20sql%20injection?))

Comment: Look at the link in the second answer, not the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a simple answer, you can use mysql_real_escape_string

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php

http://www.osempire.com/php-injection-attacks-guide

To give you a better answer, try reading Theo's answer in [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

I assume you are in the middle of the project already. Once you finish, I suggest learning a new framework like CodeIgniter, Yii and CakePHP to speed up development.