# sql injection on delete query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, sql-delete

I have this query:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email'
```

How can it be attacked by SQL injection attack that causes all of records get deleted?
`addslashes()` function is applied on `$email` before sending it to the query.

Comment: DELETE FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email' OR 1=1

Comment: @vimalnath he said addslashes is applied, so this won't work

Comment: what should be the value of $email?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You can bypass addslashes as following if the wrong encoding is set in the database (this doesn't work with UTF-8):

```
$email = urldecode('%BF%27 OR 1 -- '); // user input

$email = addslashes($email);
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE user_email = '$email'";
```

because a `\` is prepended to `%27` (`'`), `%BF` and a blackslash results in a valid multibyte char

[Here is an blog article explaining this](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `PDO` you can use `$pdo->quote($var)` or use PDOStatement `bindParam`, `bindValue($var, PDO::INT_PARAM)` that sanitizes data and avoid all public knowed special chars become used as sql injection.

**EDIT**

Thats because each databse has his own reserved words.

Comment: PDO isn't used in the code, unfortunately.