# about mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if its possible to use multiple insert query in a single php code. Like when I clicked the save button. My php code will perform multiple insertion on a same table? Is it possible?

Example: `tb_people with field 'id','name'`

I have 3 name inputs that I need to put a value if a click the save button it will save?

Example code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['save']))
  {
    $name1 = $_POST['name1'];
    $name2 = $_POST['name2'];
    $name3 = $_POST['name3'];
    mysql_query("INSERT into tb_people(name) VALUES ('$name1')");
    mysql_query("INSERT into tb_people(name) VALUES ('$name2')");
    mysql_query("INSERT into tb_people(name) VALUES ('$name2')");
  }
?>
```

Is this possible? I'm curios cause im planning to use this kind of idea.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: yes absolutely it is possible

Comment: ... yes it's possible, `VALUES ('$name1'), ('$name2'), ('$name3')`

Comment: Yes it is possible. As an added bonus, you can actually do all that with a single insert query.  Read the MySQL documentation here for syntax on how to insert multiple sets of values at once - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: http://www.hilariousgifs.com/even-possible/

Comment: This code is very insecure.  What would happen if my name was `');  DROP TABLE tb_people; -- `?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code should work.
It is better to have some protection against SQL injection as below.

- I have changed addslashes to mysql_real_escape_string. So now it should be alright.

  $name1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name1']);
  $name2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name2']);
  $name3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name3']);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tb_people` (`name`) VALUES ('$name1'), ('$name2'), ('$name3');");

Comment: `addslashes` is *not* a safe way to prevent SQL injection at all.  **Please** read the docs: http://php.net/addslashes

Comment: Please also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/860954

Comment: @RocketHazmat, The mysql_real_escape_string extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future as http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string. Other options are mysqli_real_escape_string() and PDO::quote().

Comment: The best option here would be prepared statements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. But learn more about MySQL before using it.

```
$name1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name1']);
$name2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name2']);
$name3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name3']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tb_people` (`name`) VALUES ('$name1'), ('$name2'), ('$name3');");
```

[image: xkcd]
> [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/327/)

---

You can even do this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
Repeat the above as many times as you like - you can even add more with JavaScript!
```

PHP:

```
$toinsert = array_map(function($n) {
    return "('".mysql_real_escape_string($n)."')";
},$_POST['name']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tb_people` (`name`) VALUES ".implode(", ",$toinsert));
```

MySQL is very powerful. Try doing *that* with a prepared query!

PS. If, like me, you think `mysql_real_escape_string` is a fuckton to type each time...

```
function dbesc($n) {return mysql_real_escape_string($n);}
```

Comment: I can do that with a prepared query: http://pastebin.com/3k7YYJur  Not pretty, but it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

All this is doing is calling 3 mysql queries to the database.

Your code example should work perfectly fine for that as well.