# Storing HTML file as a PHP string

Tags: php, html

I have a full HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  ...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to save it in a variable like so:

```
$template = htmlentities("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en-US">...", ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8" );
```

.. but it chokes at just the first `HTML` tag.

Comment: Err, use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the first HTML tag has double quotes, just like you use for delimiting your string literal.

```
$template = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  ...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
EOD;
```

Comment: Would just add a note for beginners like me that ending `EOD;` must not have empty space before it.

Comment: btw, it doesn't seem to recognize others variables inside the `EOD`, for example `<p class="meta">►►► BRAND NEW ◉ <?= $description ?></p>`

Comment: You wouldn't use a short echo tag in a string literal, so you wouldn't use it in a heredoc either.

Answer (score 0):

You are not escaping the string propertly Try to:
Replace

```
htmlentities("//whatever your html code is//");
```

with

```
htmlentities('//whatever your html code is//');
```

Answer (score 0):

user **addslashes** function..it will not truncate your string in between. 
This function can be used to prepare a string for storage in a database and database queries.

Before storing into database or for any purpose

```
$final_string = addslashes('<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

..........');

Before rendering that output on browser

```
$normal_string = stripslashes($database_retrived_string);
```

Comment: "This function can be used to prepare a string for storage in a database and database queries." - No, it can't.

Comment: @Ja͢ck for your information http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_addslashes.asp     http://php.net/addslashes

Comment: Preparing a string for database requires either a dedicated database escaping function or prepared statements; preparing a string for output in a browser requires  `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Why are you assuming that it's going to be stored in a database?

Comment: I have given example...we can use it for any purpose...we can use that function to storing into variable without any break and can use stripslashes to render it again...

Comment: @Prashant M Bhavsar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$temp     = addslashes('<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en-US">...', ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8" );

$template = htmlentities($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Template</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  ...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>';
```

base64_encode($data);

Comment: He would still have to manually escape all of the single quotes. Heredoc works. Not sure why he wouldn't just read the file in though...