# Error in order Detail:-Unknown column '906TB_iframe' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql

**Given Sql error "Unknown Column in Where Clause"**

```
<?php 
require_once('config.php');

    $orderId=$_REQUEST['order_Id'];

    $orderValue=OrderDetail($orderId,$dbc);

    echo '<strong>Name:-</strong>'.$orderValue["order_payment_first_name"].' '.$orderValue["order_payment_last_name"].'<br>';
    echo '<strong>Address:-</strong>'.$orderValue["order_payment_address1"].'<br>'.$orderValue["order_payment_address2"].'<br>'.$orderValue["order_payment_city"].' '.$orderValue["order_payment_state"].' '.$orderValue["order_payment_country"].'<br>';
    echo '<strong>Email:-</strong>'.$orderValue["order_payment_email"].'<br>';
    echo '<strong>Ip:-</strong>'.$orderValue["ip"].'<br>';
?>
```

How can we resolve this and how to declare a select query?

Comment: But where is **SQL** query?

Comment: actully the code is this    <?php 
require_once('config.php');
 
 $orderId=$_REQUEST['order_Id'];

 $orderValue=OrderDetail($orderId,$dbc);
 
 echo '<strong>Name:-</strong>'.$orderValue["order_payment_first_name"].' '.$orderValue["order_payment_last_name"].'<br>';
 echo '<strong>Address:-</strong>'.$orderValue["order_payment_address1"].'<br>'.$orderValue["order_payment_address2"].'<br>'.$orderValue["order_payment_city"].' '.$orderValue["order_payment_state"].' '
?>

Comment: please show the SQL query.

Comment: $selOrderItem="select * from shop_order_item where order_id=$orderId";

Comment: Keywords are SQL Injection and Prepared Statements.

Comment: Is the SQL error not fairly descriptive as to what the problem is?

Comment: Please update your question with Query

Answer (score 0):

You can add this before the query:

`$orderId = '\''.$orderId.'\'';`

You need quotes around the variable, otherwise mysql thinks the value `$orderId` is a **column** instead of a value.

Please also note that you should really take precautions for SQL injections. An easy fix is this:

`$orderId = '\''.addslashes($orderId).'\'';`

However that is not enough (see [Examples of SQL Injections through addslashes()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes)). Please use a framework (laravel, codeigniter, zend, ...) to make queries safe automatically for you if you don't know how to do this yourself. And don't ignore SQL injection problems ;)