# T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING error.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

**Hello, I'm very new to PHP and im getting this error...:**

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''arak''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /testSQL.php on line 6

**...for this line:**

```
$query = UPDATE 'arak' SET `ara` = '$ar1' Limit 0,1;
```

A little help would be appriciated :)

Comment: quote the string: **$query = "UPDATE 'arak' SET `ara` = '$ar1' Limit 0,1";**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to quote the string by ", protect the table name by ` and protect value with '

```
$query = "UPDATE `arak` SET `ara` = '$ar1' Limit 0,1";
```

Be careful, `$ar1` must be protected. For example, if `$ar1 = '33\'33'`, you could have problem.

```
$ar1 = addslashes($ar1);
$query = "UPDATE `arak` SET `ara` = '$ar1' Limit 0,1";
```

Addslashes is a first step to prevent SQL Injection, but it is not enough as [you can read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes)