# how to make the value with an " ' " on it to be put into query

Tags: php

for example, the value that needs to be passed is "The Dog's Owner" why when passing the data to the query it only recognizes the "The Dog".

---

here's the code of the index

```
  <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM bookinfo";

                        if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {
                            $count = 0;
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                $id = $row["id"];
                                $tname = $row["btitle"];
                                $quantity = $row["quantity"];
                                $name = htmlspecialchars($tname, ENT_QUOTES);
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td style='margin:20px;'>" . $id . "</td>";
                                echo "<td><button name='submit' type='submit' value='" . $name . "'>" . $name . "</button>";
                                echo "<td>" . $quantity . " left</td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                                ++$count;
                            }
                            $result->free();
                        }
                        ?>
```

---

the code to start the session

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    session_start();
    require 'include.dbh.php';
    $_SESSION['sss'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['submit'], ENT_QUOTES);
    header("Location: ../books.php");
} else {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
```

---

and the code to initiate the commands. it supposes to do a SQL query to search the book base on the session

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['sss'])) {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    } else if (!isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        header("Location: ../login.php");
        exit();
    } else {
        $butt = $_SESSION['sss'];
        require 'php/include.dbh.php';

        // -------------------------
        echo $butt;
        $read = $conn->prepare("SELECT bid, btitle, bdesc, quantity, imgpath FROM bookinfo WHERE btitle=?");
        $read->bind_param("s", $butt);
        $read->execute();
        $read->store_result();
        if ($read->num_rows > 0) {
            $read->bind_result($id, $bookname, $desc, $q, $img);
            $read->fetch();
            $read->close();
        }
        // -------------------------

        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookinfo WHERE btitle='" . $butt . "'";
        // echo $sql;
        // if ($result = $conn->query($sql)) {

        //     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //         $ID = $row['bid'];
        //         $bookname = $row['btitle'];
        //         $desc = $row['bdesc'];
        //         $q = $row['quantity'];
        //         $img = $row['imgpath'];
        //     }

        //     /*freeresultset*/
        //     $result->free();
        // }
        // $a = "SELECT bid FROM borrower WHERE gid='" . $bookname . "'";
        // if ($result = $conn->query($a)) {
        //     while ($row - $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //         $b = $row['bid'];
        //     }
        // }
    }
    ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

 <head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/up.css">
     <link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.jpg">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <script>
     var today = new Date();
     var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
     var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
     today = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy;
     document.getElementById('dob').value = Date();
     </script>
 </head>

 <body>
     <div class="content">
         <div class="header">
             <table class="heading">
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <span class="title">Seshat</span>
                         <span class="tag"> | a faster way to record books</span>
                     </td>
                     <td style="text-align: right;">
                         <span class="title">Book Details</span>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
             <hr>

             <div class="cheader">Book Details</div>
             <div class="cbody">
                 <div class="booktitle">
                     <table>
                         <tr>
                             <td>
                                 <label for="">Title: </label>
                                 <span><?php echo $bookname; ?></span>
                             </td>
                             <td>
                                 <label for="">Book ID:</label>
                                 <span name="bid"><?php echo $ID; ?></span>
                             </td>
                         </tr>
                     </table>
                 </div>
                 <hr>
                 <div>
                     <label for="">total quantity: </label>
                     <span><?php echo $q; ?></span>
                 </div>
                 <br>
                 <div class="description">
                     <label for="">Description </label>
                     <div>
                         <p>
                             <?php
                                echo $desc;
                                ?>
                         </p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="buttons">
                     <div onclick="show()" id="s" name="borrow">Borrow</div>
                     <form action="php/include.discard.php" method="POST">
                         <button value="<?php echo $bookname; ?>" type="submit" name="discard"
                             title="Delete this Book">Discard</button>
                     </form>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="cheader">Borrowers</div>
             <div class="cbody">
                 <form action="php/include.return.php" method="POST">
                     <div class="users">
                         <table border="1">
                             <thead>
                                 <td id="asize">Book ID</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Name</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Grade And Section</td>
                                 <td id="asize">LRN</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Borrowed date</td>
                                 <td id="asize">Date Of expected return</td>
                                 <td id="asize" class="v">Actions</td>
                             </thead>

                             <!-- ----------------------------------- -->

                             <?php
                                $sqlb = "SELECT * FROM borrower where gid='" . $butt . "'";
                                if ($result = $conn->query($sqlb)) {
                                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        $field1name = $row["bid"];
                                        $field2name = $row["fname"] . " " . $row["lname"];
                                        $field3name = $row["grade"] . " - " . $row["section"];
                                        $field4name = $row["lrn"];
                                        $field5name = $row["dob"];
                                        $field6name = $row["der"];
                                        $id = $row['id'];
                                        echo '<tr> 
                                            <td>' . $field1name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field2name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field3name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field4name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field5name . '</td> 
                                            <td>' . $field6name . '</td> 
                                            <td><button type="submit" name="return" value="' . $field1name . '" class="edit" title="return the books">Return</button></td>
                                        </tr>';
                                    }
                                    $result->free();
                                }
                                ?>

                             <!-- ------------------------------------------- -->

                         </table>
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
             <br>
             <hr><br>
             <div id="f">
                 <div class="cheader">Borrow Form</div>
                 <div class="cbody" id="form">
                     <span style="margin:20pt 20pt;">Student</span>
                     <form class="" action="php/include.book.php" method="post">

                         <div class="student">
                             <table class="formt">
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>First Name</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input id="nem" type="text" name="fn" value="">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>Last Name</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="text" name="ln" value="">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>Grade And Section</span><br>
                                         <input style="width:30%;" name="g" type="number" placeholder="Grade" value="">
                                         <input style="width:50%;" type="text" placeholder="Section" name="s" value="">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span style="font-size:10pt">Learner's Reference Number</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="text" name="lrn" value="">
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                         <span style="margin:20pt 20pt;">Book</span>
                         <div class="student">
                             <table class="formt">
                                 <tr>
                                     <td>
                                         <span>Book ID</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="text" name="bid">
                                     </td>
                                     <td>
                                         <span style="font-size: 8pt;">Date of Borrowing and the day of expected
                                             return</span>
                                         <br>
                                         <input type="date" id="dob" name="dob" style="width:40%;">
                                         <input type="date" name="der" style="width:40%;">
                                     </td>
                                 </tr>
                             </table>
                         </div>
                         <br>
                         <div class="buttons">
                             <button type="submit" <?php echo "value='" . $butt . "'"; ?> name="submit">Submit</button>
                             <button type="reset">Reset</button>
                         </div>
                 </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
             <div id="last">
                 <form action="php/include.book.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                     <div id="bt" class="buttons">
                         <button type="submit" name="back">Back to Main</button>
                     </div>
                 </form>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function show() {

         if (document.getElementById("f").style.height < "384px") {
             document.getElementById("f").style.transition = ".5s";
             document.getElementById("f").style.height = "384px";
             document.getElementById("f").style.opacity = "1";
             document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = "Close";
             document.getElementById("bt").style.top = "0pt";
         } else {
             document.getElementById("f").style.transition = ".5s";
             document.getElementById("f").style.height = "0px";
             document.getElementById("f").style.display = "0";
             document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = "Borrow";
             document.getElementById("bt").style.top = "-20pt";


         }
     }
     </script>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: **Too much code.** You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need to **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck, provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/im-new-to-stack-overflow-what-are-some-things-i-should-do-and-what-things-wil)**.

Comment: You are on the right track when using `$conn->prepare`. Just use `$conn->prepare` everywhere instead of concatenating input (like in `"SELECT * FROM borrower where gid='" . $butt . "'"`)

Comment: im sorry @FrankerZ im just studying it 2 days ago and it is just i was forced to do php with small amount of time left so i dont have the time to read this and that . but im trying my best. :D

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use function `addslashes($string)` so it will add slash to every single quote "The Dog\'s Owner"

Comment: See [Examples of SQL Injections through addslashes()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860954/examples-of-sql-injections-through-addslashes) for some cases where `addslashes` is not enough.