# PHP - Shorter Magic Quotes Solution

Tags: php, serialization, portability, magic-quotes

I'm writing a app that needs to be portable. I know I should disable magic quotes on the PHP configuration but in this case I don't know if I can do that, so I'm using the following code:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1)
{
    $process = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);

    while (list($key, $val) = each($process))
    {
        foreach ($val as $k => $v)
        {
            unset($process[$key][$k]);

            if (is_array($v))
            {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = $v;
                $process[] = &$process[$key][stripslashes($k)];
            }

            else
            {
                $process[$key][stripslashes($k)] = stripslashes($v);
            }
        }
    }

    unset($process);
}
```

To simplify the process of disabling magic quotes I had the following idea:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1)
{
    foreach (array('GET', 'POST', 'COOKIE', 'REQUEST') as $array)
    {
        ${'_'.$array} = unserialize(stripslashes(serialize(${'_'.$array})));
    }
}
```

But I tried and I got an error I'm unable to understand, for instance with `?name=O'Reilly`:

```
serialize($_GET); // a:1:{s:4:"name";s:9:"O\'Reilly";}
stripslashes(serialize($_GET)); // a:1:{s:4:"name";s:9:"O'Reilly";}
```

<s>But `unserialize(stripslashes(serialize($_GET)))` gives me this weird error:</s>

<s>**Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 30 of 32 bytes**</s>

---

**EDIT: Due to the length attribute in `serialize()` I changed the code to use JSON functions:**

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1)
{
    foreach (array('GET', 'POST', 'COOKIE', 'REQUEST') as $array)
    {
        ${'_' . $array} = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode(${'_' . $array})), true);
    }
}
```

However now **the `$_GET` array is coming up empty**, can anyone explain me why?

Comment: As far as I know, they won't actually remove get_magic_quotes_gpc in PHP 6, exactly because it's going to break these kind of scripts for no reason, so people convinced them that it would be a silly thing to do. Instead, it will just be marked as deprecated. Just something to keep in mind if you want to simplify the code a bit.

Comment: @Michael: The manual (http://pt2.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) still says otherwise: **This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 6.0.0.**

Comment: No, that's the part of the manual talking about magic quotes as a feature - which is indeed going to be removed. The in-progress NEWS file for PHP6 (http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/NEWS?revision=289244&view=markup) states "Changed get_magic_quotes_gpc(), get_magic_quotes_runtime to always return false and set_magic_quotes_runtime() to raise an E_CORE_ERROR.", so the functions for checking if they're enabled are still there.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks, it's nice to know that. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, I had to use the `JSON_HEX_APOS` flag in `json_encode()`:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1)
{
    $_GET = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_GET, JSON_HEX_APOS)), true);
}
```

---

**Before (`mqgpc.php?name[got'cha]=O'Reilly`):**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [got\'cha] => O\'Reilly
        )
)
```

**After (`mqgpc.php?name[got'cha]=O'Reilly`):**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [got'cha] => O'Reilly
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the second version will work. Serialized strings are stored along with their length, if you are removing characters, you would need to update that length value. I would rather implement it this way to improve readability:

```
function strip_slashes_recursive(&$value) {
    if (!is_array($value)) {
        $value = strip_slashes($value);
    } else {
        foreach (array_keys($value) as $key) {
            $arrayValue = strip_slashes_recursive($value[$key]);
            unset($value[$key]);
            $value[strip_slashes($key)] = $arrayValue;
        }
    }
}

foreach (array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST) as &$array) {
    strip_slashes_recursive($array);
}
// don't forget to unset references or it can lead to very nasty bugs
unset($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve that problem this way:

```
function smagic($params){
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
        if(!is_array($params))
            return stripslashes($params);
        else
            return array_combine( array_map('stripslashes',array_keys($params)), array_map('smagic',array_values($params)) );
    }
}
```

And then, for $_GET:

```
$_GET = smagic($_GET);
```

Comment: Doesn't handle array keys. =\

Comment: @AlixAxel You were right: Check now that I've corrected the bug ;)