# How to use mysqli_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

When i echo: 
mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, '"conn"e"cting"');

It out put: \"conn\"e\"cting\" on both my remote and local server

which is how it supposed to be, but problem is, it is saving ["conn"e"cting"] to database in my local database, while saving [\"conn\"e\"cting\"] with the back slashes to my remote database. Should I configure my remote database? How? I'm using nearlyfreespeech's service.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a `magic_quotes` issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your remote `php.ini` has [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled.

You can check by running...

```
var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc()); // True means it is enabled
```

It will escape all the GET, POST & COOKIE super globals automatically - but then escaping again will leave you with a slash that will be inserted.

Disable magic quotes on your server, or use a magic quotes disabler functions if disabling them in impossible.

#### Update

For the hell of it, here is one I just made up

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {

   function stripSlashesRecursive($array) {
       $stripped = array();
       foreach($array as $key => $member) {
          if (is_array($member)) {
             $stripped[stripslashes($key)] = stripSlashesRecursive($member);
          } else {
              $stripped[stripslashes($key)] = stripslashes($member);
          }
       }

       return $stripped;
    }

    $globals = array('_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE', '_REQUEST');
    
    foreach($globals as $global) {
       $$global = stripSlashesRecursive($$global);
    }



}
```

[It works!](http://codepad.org/5QD42xd1)

Comment: You should rephrase your first sentence, remote databases never have magic_quotes enabled...

Comment: @alex: **remote** php.ini? Also, this code doesn't make much sense... You're cleaning GPC and assigning it to the $global variable, the problem is this variable is only defined *iff* `if get_magic_quotes_gpc()`.

Comment: @Alix Axel Whoops, maybe I shouldn't program on Sundays... How does it look now?

Comment: tried your code, didn't work. but it did point me to this code: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php thanks guys/girls. it's very much appreciated!

Comment: @alex: `array('$_GET', '$_POST', '$_COOKIE')` should be `array('_GET', '_POST', '_COOKIE')`, and I doubt that either one will work (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077711/php-shorter-magic-quotes-solution).

Comment: @Alix Axel Made that fix already buddy :) What do you mean you doubt it will work? [Am I doing something wrong?](http://codepad.org/5QD42xd1).

Comment: @alex: Sorry, I linked to the wrong post (and hadn't refreshed this page)... I can't find the right one but I wrote a similar code in the past and I discovered that **you can't alter a superglobal using variable variables**, try it - that's the reason why I work each superglobal individually in my answer.

Comment: @Alix Axel It worked for me, but I did assign the super globals myself. Edit: Tried it with `$_GET` and adding them in the address bar, and it worked perfectly :)

Comment: @alex: `Please note that variable variables cannot be used with PHP's Superglobal arrays within functions or class methods.`: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php.

Comment: @Alix Axel But I'm not within a function or class method? :P

Comment: @Alix Axel Now you can stop picking on me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're running PHP 5.3, this should do the trick:

```
if ((get_magic_quotes_gpc() === 1) && (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '>=') === true))
{
    $_GET = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_GET, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT)), true);
    $_POST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_POST, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT)), true);
    $_COOKIE = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_COOKIE, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT)), true);
    $_REQUEST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_HEX_APOS | JSON_HEX_QUOT)), true);
}
```

Comment: I am using PHP 5.3.1, and I got `NULL` when running an array with escaped chars through.

Comment: @alex: I just turned `register_globals` on and tested it again on the `$_GET` superglobal. Worked just fine on PHP 5.3.1...

Comment: What's the deal with the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

I think an easier solution is to set the php.ini directive for **runtime** magic quotes to 0 in your script, like so:

```
ini_set('magic_quotes_runtime', '0');
```

Magic_quotes_gpc is a separate directive which only applies to Get/Post/Cookie operations, Axil.
The ini_set() function can be used to change php.ini settings temporarily(the lifetime of the script). It will ensure that you get the same behavior across all servers. the parameters are the name of the directive you want to set and the new value, both in the form of strings.

Good luck!