# Weird text addition in PHP

Tags: php

I have a form posting data to a php page. Then I have the PHP page echoing the data aswell as posting it to twitter. Whenever In a word with an apostrophe it adds a back-slash right before it. So I type in "I'm going to the park" it echos "I\'m going to the park" what's going on and how do I fix it? Thanx :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a **stripslashes()** around the content before submitting it.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by [`magic_quotes`](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc), a configuration option you should turn off. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220437/magic-quotes-in-php) for good explanations.

Answer (score 1):

you can turn it off in the php.ini or .htaccess

or just get rid in place:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) foreach($_POST as $k=>$v) $_POST['$k'] = stripslashes($v);
```

Answer (score -1):

magic_quotes_gpc is on.. i'd turn it off in your php.ini or server settings panel (depending on your host)

edited to the, although somewhat painful, support of Col. Shrapnel..

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Please elaborate.

Comment: try it and see if it really works. then try to think - why. It is not too hard to make assistance necessary ;)

Comment: &#$^@&*#$@ it can't be disabled at run-time - *pounds fist onto desk*